# Why is the alignment in accounts page for Area51 different than the rest?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, area-51

Nothing really important but Area51's account page looks different from the rest of the account pages. Area51 one is aligned in colums while the other SE sites are arranged like row. Here's a couple picts to demonstrate this:

Area51:

[image: Area51]

Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow]

Anyone care to explain why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Area 51 codebase was forked from the Stack Exchange codebase around May (or possibly even earlier). What you see at Area 51 was what the Accounts page *used* to look like on all SE sites, and the change to the new compact version was made on or around [July 28](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/16640/revisions). The change was not pulled from the SE codebase into the Area 51 codebase, so it remains as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd offer to explain this page's difference is that people would be coming to Area 51 from a variety of SE/Trilogy sites, so an explicit *Copy Profile From X* button for each associated account would be useful. On other sites, the operation is in reverse: you can copy your profile to other sites.

But Area 51's theme is drastically different than SE/Trilogy sites to begin with, and presumably that's because Area 51 is of a drastically different scope.

Comment: True, but it still would seem kind of stupid, why not just go the site you want to copy the stuff?